# How to select row in table jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have a table with following columns

```
|type |status |owner |host |
```

I need to select the rows which contain for example (type1 or ... or type20) && (status1 or ... status5) && (owner1 or .. or owner4) etc.

I know that if I need to have the rows which contains type1&&owner2&&staus1 I can do the following

```
$(table tr:contains('type1'):contains('owner2'):contains('status1'));
```

Can someone explain how to handle this?

Answer (score 2):

I would use something like this:

```
var $rows =  $('table tr').filter(function() {
    return ...;
});
```

where `...` is the predicate for matching the cells you want.

Don't forget that you can use `this.cells[n]` to directly and efficiently access the individual cells, and `.textContent` (or `.innerText`) to read the cells' values.

So, part of your predicate could be:

```
this.cells[0].textContent.match(/^type([1-9]|1[0-9]|20)$/)
```

Comment: It seems that cell[i] does not work for those cells which have style="display:none;"

Comment: @Gayane the `cells[i]` should exist for every cell, hidden or otherwise.  However you may not be able to get `.innerText` for a hidden cell.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent